# Google Places API - Location near Landmark

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I was wondering if it is possible to limit the Google Places API to search only for **'x'** near **'landmark'** where landmark is limited to landmarks only.

For example:

```
Not desired: coffee shop near Walmart

Desired: coffee shop near Eiffel Tower
```

Using javascript API.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

> A Places Nearby search is initiated with a call to the PlacesService's
>   nearbySearch() method, which will return an array of PlaceResult
>   objects.
>
> ```
> service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
> service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
> ```
>
> You must also pass a callback method to nearbySearch(), to handle the
>   results object and google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus response.
>
> ```
> var map;
> var service;
> var infowindow;
>
> function initialize() {
>   var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);
>
>   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
>       center: pyrmont,
>       zoom: 15
>     });
>
>   var request = {
>     location: pyrmont,
>     radius: '500',
>     types: ['store']
>   };
>
>   service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
>   service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
> }
>
> function callback(results, status) {
>   if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
>     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
>       var place = results[i];
>       createMarker(results[i]);
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

You'd change the LatLng of `pyrmont` to change the location, in your case, The Eiffeltower. You could also change all occurrences of `pyrmont` to your own variable. `shop` could also be changed.

Comment: This doesn't particularly answer the question as far as I can see... the question wonders whether 'landmarks' are a type of place in google places API and whether I can restrict the second argument to landmarks only.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do two searches:

1. Lookup the candidate **landmark** using a `PlacesService`'s `textSearch` method.  If the top result matches your definition of landmark (perhaps the `types` array includes `point_of_interest`?), then use its location in step 2.
2. Use `PlacesService`'s `nearbySearch` to do a search for `keyword`=**x** around that location.

Something like:

```
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

var request = {
    query: "Eiffel Tower",
    types: ["point_of_interest"]
}

function extractTopLandmark(results, status) {
    // Give up if no landmark was found
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) return;
    if (results.length < 1) return;
    // We have a landmark, use its location to do a nearby search.
    var request = {
        keyword: "coffee shop",
        location: results[0].geometry.location,
        radius: 500
    };
    service.nearbySearch(request, addMarkers);
}

function addMarkers(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

service.textSearch(request, extractTopLandmark);
```

Comment: I'll give this a go, thanks for your input. I'm busy for a day or two so let me mark it correct if it works when I check it out.

Comment: No worries.  I'm looking forward to hearing how this approach works out for you.